# Rails: pretty_id - hide the resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to setup a pretty url that does not show the resource on the route.

For example, instead of:

```
localhost/users/newton
```

show

```
localhost/newton
```

Is that possible with the pretty_id gem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think you mean the friendly_id gem?  Either way, you can, but in the routes file, you would just need to specify that you want to use the users controller.

```
get ':slug' => 'users#show', :as => 'user_show'
```